# Join 270 columns in PySpark

Tags: join, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I ran into an issue when joining a massive number of columns.

I have 270 data outputs with the same data schema. And the 270 outputs need to be joined into one big table, is there any way to optimize join? It costs a lot of time now.

Currently, we use `A.join(B,'userid')`. Thank you.
[Table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFlVO.png)

Comment: Schema is like this:  userid: int, type_X_count: int. The number of rows in each data output is the same. The 'X' in 'type_X_count' is different in each data output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [unionAll](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionAll).

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
```

You can use [unionByName](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.unionByName) if it better suits your purpose. Please read the documentation and validate.

**Note: The order of the columns in the dataframes should be the same for this to work. This can silently give unexpected results if you don't have the correct column orders!!**

Comment: Hi, Pissall, thank you for the suggestion. Our current goal is too get a master table with 271 columns, like userid, type_1_count, type_2_count,..., type_270_count, a flatten table. Is there any way to build a table like this?

Comment: I think you might get name ambiguity issues in that approach. But other than that you will have to use a for loop

Comment: It wont have name ambiguity issues because each type column name is different from the rest. Actually, instead of using join, I union all the dataframe first then use pivot function, it turns into a table with 271 columns. It takes less than 20 mins to finish including the time writing to parquet files. It is more acceptable than before.